# How can I implement Gmail android app-like user account switching?

Tags: android, gmail, android-view

In a recent Gmail android app update, you now have the ability to right swipe on a user account view to switch to another account.

How can such account switching be implemented ?

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

[image]

Comment: regarding the UI animation or the actual backend?

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=navigation+drawer ?

Comment: I suppose they are google, they can switch between google accounts if they want. I doubt commonfolk could do the same thing, and I'd love to see if someone figures out a way.

Comment: @aindurti : Yes , how is the UI animation working ?

Comment: @VihaanVerma take a look at this library, it does what you are looking for and you can just go through the code to see how its done https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer

Comment: @VihaanVerma - i am using this library, and it gives good results, you can check it out too !! - https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer